# Making 2D Array of Strings in C

Tags: c, arrays, character

I am working on a project for my CS1 class and I have run into something I have never thought of before. I know at all arrays in C are essentially pointer to the first element of an array, and a string is really just a character array. However, for my assignment we have to read in a file, and part of the file is the following:

```
Brad Tim Rick (more man names separated by spaces)
Lucy Angela Tina (more women names separated by spaces)
```

This is a short example, but what I have to do is extract the names and store them into two separate arrays, one for men and one for females.

I have never worked with something like this, so of course I am confused. This is what I am trying to do, and of course its not working... oh yeah, and I'm trying to store them in dynamic allocation. The only spec says that the names will never exceed 19 characters (should I say twenty to allow the '/0' at the end of the string to still be there no matter what?) How can I tell the compiler, "hey I want an array of strings, and each string can hold 19 characters + 1 for the "string trailer '/0' "? And then how do I access those through pointers?

```
char **mens_names, **womens_names;

mens_names = malloc(number_of_couples * sizeof(char[19]));
womens_names = malloc(number_of_couples * sizeof(char[19]));

if(mens_names == NULL){
printf("Malloc failed! Memory could not be allocated to variable mens_names.");
return -1;
}

int i;
for(i = 0; i < number_of_couples; i++){
    fscanf(input_file, "%s", &mens_names[i]);
}


if(womens_names == NULL){
    printf("Malloc failed! Memory could not be allocated to variable womens_names.");
    return -1;
}

for(i = 0; i < number_of_couples; i++){
    fscanf(input_file, "%s", &womens_names[i]);
}

for(i = 0; i < number_of_couples; i++){
    printf("Man: %s ", mens_names[i]);
    printf("Woman: %s\n", womens_names[i]);
}
```

Comment: Not sure what your question is? A few comments though: `sizeof(char[19])` is just long syntax for `19`; yes, you will actually need 20 for the null terminator; you can make sure to avoid buffer overruns with width specifiers, e.g.: `fscanf(input_file, "%19s", ...)`.

Comment: I have to make a 2d char array, using pointers, that will hold the list of name. So in memory, my arrays will look like for the mentioned example: 

mens_names:
{'B' 'r' 'a' 'd' '/0',
'T' 'o' 'm' '/0',
'R' 'i' 'c' 'k' '/0'} and I want to do it dynamically so it can be ten names, one hundred names, one thousand names, etc.

Comment: I understand what you need to do. What I don't understand however, is how exactly you want us to help you. You say you tried something and it's not working. How exactly is it not working? What results do you have? What results do you want?

Comment: When I am trying to print the values the program crashes. I do not know how to watch pointers in codeblocks (what my professor requires us to code in), and it crashes when I try and access mens_names[i], however since it is a string, I am unsure how to "read string in row 1, read string in row 2, read string in row 3, ... , read string in row n"

Comment: Arrays and pointers are very different things. I suggest you read [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com/) maybe starting with section 6.

Comment: I'm still having no luck. Thanks for trying to help though! I guess I just need to learn how to "ask my question better".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know at all arrays in C are essentially pointer to the first element of an array

Not quite.  Arrays and pointers are two different things entirely.  Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof`, `_Alignof`, or unary `&` operator, or is a string literal being used to initialize an array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" **will be converted** to an expression of type "pointer to `T`" and its value will be the address of the first element in the array.

Given the declaration

```
int a[10];
```

the *object* that `a` designates is always and forever a 10-element array of `int`; however, the *expression* `a` may be treated as a pointer to the first element.

If you *know* your strings will never be more than 19 characters long (20 elements including the terminator), but don't know the number of strings ahead of time, you can do something like this:

```
char (*mens_names)[20];
char (*womens_names)[20];
...
mens_names = malloc(number_of_couples * sizeof *mens_names);
womens_names = malloc(number_of_couples * sizeof *womens_names);
...
fscanf(input_file, "%s", mens_names[i]);
...
free(mens_names);
free(womens_names);
```

In this case, we've declared `mens_names` and `womens_names` as pointers to 20-element arrays of `char` (the parentheses matter).  Thus, `sizeof *mens_names` is equivalent to `sizeof (char [20])`.

You would access each individual character as you would with a regular 2-d array:

```
char x = mens_names[i][j];
```

`mens_names[i]` implicitly dereferences the `mens_names` pointer (remember that the expression `a[i]` is interpreted as `*(a + i)`).

This method has a couple of advantages over KBart's method.  First, all the memory is allocated contiguously as a single chunk, which may matter if caching becomes an issue.  Secondly, you only need one `malloc` and one `free` for each array.  Of course, this assumes that the maximum size of each name array is a) fixed and b) known at compile time.

If you won't know the size of the name until runtime, and you're using a C99 compiler or a C2011 compiler that supports variable-length arrays, you can do something like this:

```
size_t name_len, number_of_couples;
// get name_len from the user or input file
// get number_of_couples
char (*mens_names)[name_len+1] = malloc(number_of_couples * sizeof *mens_names);
...
```

If you won't know the size of the name until runtime, and you're using a compiler that *doesn't* support VLAs, then you'll need to use KBart's method.

If you wanted to get *really* fancy, you could use a single 3-dimensional array instead of two 2-dimensional arrays:

```
#define MENS_NAMES 0
#define WOMENS_NAMES 1
...
char (*all_names)[2][20] = malloc(number_of_couples * sizeof *all_names);
...
fscanf(input_file, "%s", all_names[i][MENS_NAMES]);
...
free(all_names);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are talking about 2D array, but initializing it only as a one dimensional array. The correct initialization of 2D array (matrix) is as follows:

```
static char** allocate_matrix(int nrows, int ncols) 
{
    int i;
    char **matrix;

    /*  allocate array of pointers  */
    matrix = malloc( nrows*sizeof(char*));

    if(matrix==NULL)
        return NULL; /* Allocation failed */

    /*  Allocate column for each name  */
    for(i = 0; i < nrows; i++)
        matrix[i] = malloc( ncols*sizeof(char));

    if(matrix[i-1] == NULL) 
        return NULL; /* Allocation failed */

    return matrix;
}
```

In your *main()*:

```
<...>
mens_names = allocate_matrix(number_of_couples, 19);
womens_names = allocate_matrix(number_of_couples, 19);
<...>

/* Of course, do not forget to free memory once you are done */
```

Comment: One question, why did you use matrix = malloc( nrows*sizeof(char*));
 when nrows is a type integer?

Comment: If you malloc() in a loop you need to free() in a loop, to handle the individual pointers, I think. One malloc for the whole matrix would be possible also,since the size is fixed,  but I think its clearer this way.

Comment: @dsiebert424 the malloc parameter "size" is the number of bytes to allocate. The type of nrows does not matter (if the calculation just results in the cirrect number of bytes).

Comment: @thuovila, yes you are absolutely correct about freeing. It was just a side note, so I did not put much thought in it. The correct way should be writing a simple function that frees every column first.

Answer (score 0):

```
void init(char**** tab,int size1d,int size2d,int size_string)
{
    int iterator;
    int iterator_2;

    char*** temp = (char***) calloc(size1d,sizeof(char**));
    for (iterator = 0 ; iterator < size1d;iterator++)
    {
        *(temp+iterator) = (char**) calloc(size2d,sizeof(char*));

        for (iterator_2 = 0;iterator_2 < size2d;iterator_2++)
        {
            *(*(temp+iterator)+iterator_2) = (char*) calloc(size_string,sizeof(char));
        }
    }

    *tab = temp;
}

int main()
{
    char*** tab;

    init(&tab,100,100,255);
    tab[5][99] = "Hi";

    printf("%s",tab[5][99]);
}
```

Comment: Adding an explanation on how this code answers the question would benefit future visitors.